# Android Maps API 2 SHA-1 Key usage

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am reading the [google maps android API v2 setup document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=it) and it says I need to provide my app's SHA-1 fingerprint in order to get a key to access the API.

This sounds really cumbersome, because some times I just enjoy to make some quick tests in the code, to test some ideas and see if everything is behaving as it should (who doesnt?) but every new build I make I will have a different SHA-1 fingerprint, and instead of just do some iterations of simple programming and testing, I will need to be also changing the API's key all the time? Is this really needed? Sounds frustrating.

Comment: "but every new build I make I will have a different SHA-1 fingerprint" -- why? Nobody else does it that way. The fingerprint is of your **signing key**, not the app.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion, I thought it was the app's SHA-1 not it's certificate SHA-1 haha, do you mind to place it as an answer so I can close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SHA-1 fingerprint used by the Maps V2 API key system is the fingerprint of your signing key. You will at least have a debug signing key, plus perhaps 1+ production signing keys. For a modest number of such keys, you can associate all their SHA-1 fingerprints with the same Maps V2 API key.

What *isn't* used is some SHA-1 hash of your APK. Hence, you will only need to worry about your SHA-1 fingerprints when you create or replace signing keys, not on every build.